# Tate models for semistable algebraic varieties with mixed reduction over a local field

Tags: rigid-analytic-geometry, abelian-varieties, nt.number-theory

It's known that if $A$ is an abelian variety of totally multiplicative reduction over a p-adic field K, then, after taking a finite field extension, it becomes isomorphic, as a rigid analytic group, to $G_m^g/\prod_{i=1}^g q_i^{\mathbb{Z}}$ where $q_i$ are points (after a finite field extension) of $G_m^g$ which generate a discrete subgroup.

My question is, what can be said when $A$ is not totally multiplicative or good reduction, but is some semistable abelian variety of mixed multiplicative-good reduction. I would guess that instead of being a quotient of $G_m$ by a discrete subgroup, $A$ will be (as a rigid analytic variety) a quotient of a good-reduction semi-abelian variety (i.e. a variety which is an extension by $G_m^m$ of an abelian variety of good reduction) by a free discrete subgroup. Does anyone know whether this is true, or whether there's something else replacing the Tate uniformization in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $A$ has semi-abelian reduction, then $A$ is uniformized by a semi-abelian variety $G_A$,
namely there is an exact sequence
$$0 \to \Gamma_A \to G_A \to A \to 0,$$
where $\Gamma_A$ is free of finite rank, $G_A$ is semi-abelian, and the maximal abelian variety quotient of $G_A$ has good reduction.

This is due to Raynaud, I believe, and is also discussed in SGA 7.
For precise references, allow me (out of laziness) to cite [one of my papers](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/optimal.pdf) --- see the
discussion at the beginning of Section 3.

Comment: Just a little comment. In fact, the whole semi-abelian variety $G_A$ has good reduction: it extends to a split semi-abelian scheme over the ring of integers.

Comment: Also, the Raynaud reference is:  `Variétés abéliennes et géométrie rigide'. Actes du Congrès International des Mathématiciens (Nice, 1970), Tome 1, pp. 473–477. Gauthier-Villars, Paris, 1971